# How Keyboard events of a desktop website are simulated in mobile website using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have some function tied to keyboard arrow keys events in desktop website using JQuery.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
switch (e.which) {
    case 37: //left
         doIT("leftside");
         Break;
    case 38: //up
         doIT("upside");
         Break;
    case 39: //right
         doIT("rightside");
         Break;
    case 40: //down
         doIT("downside");
         Break;
}
```

}

These are working fine on desktop website, but not on mobile website.
(I know we can't access arrow keys in mobile)

I want those corresponding functions to be executed in mobile website.
(if user swipes to left/up/right/down on mobile website)

can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this, especially with swipes as swipes are a combination of different events (i.e. keydown, keyhold, keyup) .

Picking up swipes via keyup and keydown events can be very difficult. It would be better to use a plugin which can explicitly detect swipes such as [Hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/)

Comment: Now I got the clarity. This would be the right plugin for my objective.

Answer (score 0):

jquery mobile has events for `swipeleft` and `swiperight`

For up and down yo have to use the scrollstart and scrollstop events to detect in which direction the scroll is going.

```js
var start = 0;

$(document).on("scrollstart", function() {
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
  start = $(window).scrollTop();
});

$(document).on("scrollstop", function() {
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
  var end = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (start - end < 0) {
    console.log("Scrolled down");
    doIT("downside");

  } else {
    console.log("Scrolled up");
    doIT("upside");
  }
});

$(document).on("swipeleft", function() {
  doIT("rightside");
  console.log("right");
});

$(document).on("swipeleft", function() {
  doIT("leftside");
  console.log("right");
});
```

Comment: My Website is not scrollable.
but swipeleft and swiperight events are useful for me.